# create a task in BPEL using java code

Tags: oracle, bpel

I am creating a BPEL process, in which my requirement is I need to create a task based on some inputs and assign it to partucular user, and then come out from that flow.

earlier I had impression that i will use Human task Activity. but when I am using that Task will be created in the itself process and instance will stucked out over there untill human intervention(the BPEL process is waiting on result.).

is there any way I can use Java embed activity and create task from java code, "I know how to assign a job to particular user". please tell me.
Abhishek

Comment: Now i  am able to initiate a task but not able to create payload for that task, If any one have any idea please share

Comment: Human Tasks are not part of the BPEL specification. Please tell us which product you are using, otherwise it is impossible to give an answer (to a product specific question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the Human Task Flow as well by clicking the + sign. It is a normal scope, just with a different icon. In there you should see an `Invoke` and `Receive`. Just drop the Receive to ignore it, if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow this link  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12483_01/integrate.1013/b28987/phase10.htm. Basically all you have to do is create a human task in your composite file and then link it to your BPEL process. Once you are done drop the human task icon in the flow. Also do not delete the receive as ZeissS says but continue to process in a parallel flow as then you won't get an exception and roll back when the human task finishes.

If you do want to do this in a java process grab the WSHumanTask compliant WSDL and invoke the relevant operations as per the OASIS standard.